# Mssql vs mysql for software development

Tags: mysql, singlestore

My team and I are developing a database software. We came a long way working with MS SQL server. The project we are working on is also based on MS SQL. After we are done with the software, we want to sell it. But for quiet some time, a matter has been bothering us . Which one should we use, MS SQL or MySQL? We've been working on our software for 2 months now and all this time we have been using MS SQL server . But still we're confused! Because if we make a software MS SQL server when a user/client buys our product, he has to buy ms sql server as well(correct me if i'm wrong) to load the database we're providing with our product . Now coming to MySql, this one is an open-source . But as I've mentioned our project is till this date is based on MS SQL . I really need your opinion . If u guys can, then please tell me which one I should go with?

Comment: I voted to close this question.  But for the record, put my vote in for Postgres over MySQL.  Also note that MS SQL has free versions, which might be suitable for your product.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a really good question, but it is not a good fit for what Stack Overflow wants to see on the site. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: any suggested forums where i should post this ?

Comment: Super short answer, if the intent is to make this a commerical product around database and without knowing what your product exactly is first thought comes to mind is you should consider supporting more then one database.   Client requirements differ from client to client... most common thing that comes to mind is maybe the client shop is entirely MS stack based or maybe it's already using MySQL or some other db....

Comment: okey...so it depends on what db software the client is using already ? but in general,which one should i pick rather than depending on client's pre-installed one ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  The system will likely throttle or block posts from you soon since they all have scores of 0 (worthless) or negative (bad)..  When it does, dont be surprised or whine that no one told you.

Comment: @ronnie: Stack Exchange has a site specifically for asking for software recommendations: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Just from my previous experience using both... I’ve used both professionally, it shouldn’t be difficult to make the switch but it depends on how much data you plan on handling, for a lot of data I would stick with mssql server. If your application won’t be holding a lot of data I would go with MySQL. I personally, think the syntax and code for mssql server is easier but that’s just me. They aren’t really that different you would just have to change a few connections, and your query and connection strings. Yes, with mysql it will be a ten ton times better using this to sell the software. So if you’re looking for a hands off way to transfer the database as well I’d switch all my code for mysql and set up to use mysql. You will then ensure an easy transfer of data

Comment: But mySql also costs a lot ...i've just visited it's website and the prices for the community editions were like 2k/5k/10k per year...

Comment: and i am developing a vb.net software...and have no experience with mysql before...so should i stick to mssql ?

Comment: and i must add...my software will handle a tons of data

Comment: Note: `mysql` and `mariadb` (a fork that works 1:1 as mysql) are both available as open source and you can run them on your own infrastructure (and in turn the buyer can run that infrastructure themselves).

Comment: as i see, there are not so much of difference when it comes to coding ...so what if i develop for both the sqls ?

Comment: will it be a waste of time ?

Comment: While I do not want to directly influence a business decision regarding a commercial software you're developing I can tell what I, personally, would do. If I was not 100% certain of the system the buyer will use and had the time & capability to write code for both then I would write both. I would write a function for 1 system then immediately write the comparable function for the other system - making sure it returns the exact same result. If you are doing testing then run both sets of function through their own unit tests but test both systems with the same integration tests.